# Сортировка по DayOfWeek, неделя начинается с понедельника

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Есть табличка с расписанием (день недели + где), в основе лежит [`enum DayOfWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }

    public int? PlaceId { get; set; }

    public Place Place { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

И мне для людей приходится делать сортировку по возрастанию дней недели, например:

```
return await this.ApplicationDbContext.Schedule
                 .Where(x => x.PlaceId != null)
                 .OrderBy(x => x.DayOfWeek)
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .ToListAsync();
```

И всё было бы прекрасно, но сайт делается для тех стран, где неделя начинается с понедельника (Россия), а не с воскресенья.

А `DayOfWeek` начинается с воскресенья:

```
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    Sunday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
}
```

Есть ли какой-то простой способ указать сортировку "первый день недели - понедельник"?

Comment: Написать свой компаратор?

Comment: @tym32167 Компараторы нормально транслируются в sql или выполняются на клиенте? А вообще, было бы здорово.

Comment: ах, что это БД я пропустил :) Тогда компаратор скорее всего не прокатит

Comment: Угу, первая мысль - компаратор. Однако, [пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18692433/5045688), что это не работает с БД.

Comment: а зачем именно DayofWeek? почему не написать свою структуру, в которой дни будут начинаться с понедельника?

Comment: Я думал, что в штатном DayofWeek предусмотрели связь с current culture (

Comment: Не пробовал с базами данных, но может быть, поможет `OrderBy(x => (x.Date - (понедельник в древности)).TotalDays % 7)`?

Comment: @AK `var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo( "ru-RU" );` -
`var dateTimeInfo = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat;`

Comment: @AK На мой взгляд метка [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] тут нерелевантна, так как нет вообще никакой вебной специфики.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Попробуйте "магию" (на самом деле это просто циклический сдвиг дней внутри недели):

```
.OrderBy(x => ((int)x.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7)
```

В дерево выражений эта лямбда [раскладывается нормально](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLAChYMQFjZ+JAOgBkBLAOwEd8MKBDAWwFMBnAB3oGNm4AVNgBcMAbwxwJCAEzYA7OMlj0kldgBsCHNgAcACiQwA2gF049AE4BzVgEoFquEocOAbhbisAFs2ABXADZscAC8cBTMAO5w5KyCADwAylzefoEAfLo2+M6qbuZw5kGhXj4BbEQAgqwAir7M5gCe9ABGgZn2OZ1dRADy5sD1AEINugAeIWlwurqUgjajRAAi9A09AGYA6szMANZwYHBqNnAApHCyWR0qAL4dt+gdUADM0nBJKWUdTs7PcMurm22e3+6y2u0ccEszEEyA80Nh9xuGGuQA===), думаю, EF сумеет транслировать это дерево в SQL-запрос (сам не проверял).

Метод хорош тем, что простой сменой константы `6` можно сменить и требуемое начало недели.

Как спрятать формулу и привести запрос в более читабельный вид можно посмотреть в этом топике: [Как составить дерево выражения для лямбды?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/823830/218063)

---

Дополнение. Действительно, подобный запрос транслируется вполне нормально.

Исходный запрос был:

```
SELECT
    [t0].[Id],
    [t0].[DayOfWeek],
    [t0].[Notes],
    [t0].[PlaceId]
FROM [Schedule] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[PlaceId] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [t0].[DayOfWeek]
```

Со сдвигом дня недели получается такой:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 6
DECLARE @p1 Int = 7
-- EndRegion
SELECT
    [t0].[Id],
    [t0].[DayOfWeek],
    [t0].[Notes],
    [t0].[PlaceId]
FROM [Schedule] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[PlaceId] IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ([t0].[DayOfWeek] + @p0) % @p1
```

Comment: Транслируется-то он нормально, вот только индекс такой запрос использовать не сможет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а что делать? Индекс-то можно и добавить, на нашей планете неделя может начинаться с Воскресенья, Понедельника и Субботы. Добавим три индекса.

Comment: Полгода спустя я тут ковыряюсь в `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.Dump();` и подумал, что ответ можно улучшить, если заменить магическую константу 6 на выражение использующее `(int)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek`

Comment: @AK, я не спец в ASP.NET, `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` — это не настройки культуры на сервере?

Comment: А вообще, если посмотреть [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/824104/218063), там я указываю начало недели так: `BuildDayIndexInWeekSelector<Schedule>(s => s.DayOfWeek, weekStartsWith: DayOfWeek.Monday)`

Answer (score 3):

Почему не создать собственное перечисление и пользоватся? например,

```
public enum DayOfWeekRussian
{
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
}
```

Comment: А как им пользоваться, если приложение в том числе должно работать и в других странах?

Comment: возможно, нужно учитывать регион и использовать то или иное перечисление, например в региональных (языковых) настройках (если такие есть), что-то в этом роде

Comment: А как создать в классе свойство, которое будет иметь тот или иной тип по требованию? И при этом, чтобы EF нормально всё это транслировал в БД

Comment: имеете ввиду отдельный клаcс с нужными свойствами и который будет описывать данные, для передачи этого экземпляра класса (объекта) в EF? например,

`public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Простой способ указать сортировку "первый день недели - понедельник"

WinForms C#:

```
  DateTime startOfTheMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
  int daysOfTheWeek = Convert.ToInt32(startOfTheMonth.DayOfWeek.ToString("d"));
```

Comment: И как данный код помогает решить проблему?

Comment: Старайтесь давать развёрнутые ответы.