# Как составить дерево выражения для лямбды?

Tags: c#, linq, деревья-выражений

Контекст — этот вопрос: [Сортировка по DayOfWeek, неделя начинается с понедельника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/821745/218063)

Хочется отрефакторить код сортировки и вместо непонятной лямбды

```
s => ((int)s.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7
```

написать что-то вроде

```
s => GetDayNumberInWeek(s.DayOfWeek, weekStartsWith: DayOfWeek.Monday)
```

Выясняется, что деревья выражений не поддерживают именованные параметры, т.е. придется писать менее понятно:

```
s => GetDayNumberInWeek(s.DayOfWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
```

Пусть так, но как это сделать? Если написать

```
static int GetDayNumberInWeek(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, DayOfWeek weekStartsWith)
{
    int daysInWeek = 7;
    return ((int)dayOfWeek + daysInWeek - (int)weekStartsWith) % daysInWeek;
}
```

То сортировка, понятно, начнет выполняться на клиентской стороне, а этого не хочется.

Если я возвращаю из метода любой `Expression`, то EF ругается на отсутствие реализации `IComparable`.

Есть ли вообще решение у такой задачи?

Comment: Вам нужен метод,  который вернет всю лямбду целиком,  включая определение параметра,  а не только правую часть.

Comment: @PashaPash, я думал об этом, но тогда получится метод, который невозможно переиспользовать, он будет зависеть от конкретной сущности (класс Schedule). Или в нем можно будет вычленить отдельно `GetDayNumberInWeek`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно генерировать всю лямбду целиком, а не только правую часть.

На более простом примере, чтобы не шумело создание Body:

Пусть у вас есть:

```
context.Schedules
    .OrderBy(s => s.DayOfWeek)
    .ToList();
```

И вы хотите строить key selector для динамически:

Выносим селектор целиком:

```
context.Schedules
    .OrderBy(BuildKeySelector())
    .ToList();

private static Expression<Func<Schedule, DayOfWeek>> BuildKeySelector()
{
    return s => s.DayOfWeek;
}
```

И разворачиваем сгенерированный код:

```
context.Schedules
    .OrderBy(BuildDayOfWeekSelector())
    .ToList();

private static Expression<Func<Schedule, DayOfWeek>> BuildDayOfWeekSelector()
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Schedule), "s"); // левая часть 

    // правая часть, тут должно быть более сложное дерево
    var body = Expression.MakeMemberAccess( 
        parameter,
        typeof(Schedule).GetProperty("DayOfWeek"));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Schedule, DayOfWeek>>(body, parameter);

    return lambda;
}
```

Если надо отвязать BuildDayOfWeekSelector от Schedule - просто сделайте его Generic (но придется указывать тип при вызове).

```
private static Expression<Func<T, DayOfWeek>> BuildDayOfWeekSelector<T>()
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "s"); // левая часть 

    var body = Expression.MakeMemberAccess( // правая часть
        parameter,
        typeof(T).GetProperty("DayOfWeek"));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DayOfWeek>>(body, parameter);

    return lambda;
}
```

Остаток динамики - параметр weekStartsWith - спускайте параметром в BuildKeySelector и используйте при построении body как `Expression.Constant(weekStartsWith);`

Точное дерево, которое надо строить руками, можно легко подсмотреть - сделать extract local для сгенерированной компилятором лямбды, и развернуть ее в отладчике.

Comment: *Если надо отвязать BuildDayOfWeekSelector от Schedule - просто сделайте его Generic* - а свойство в нем искать как? `GetProperty("DayOfWeek")` - я бы не сказал, что это мы отвязались от Schedule. Может можно тоже как-то в виде выражения передавать? Типа `BuildDayOfWeekSelector<Schedule>(s => s.DayOfWeek)`? Получится такое?

Comment: @АндрейNOP - да, можно. Объявляете в `BuildDayOfWeekSelector` параметр типа `Expression<Func<T, DayOfWeek>>`. Кодом достаете из этого Expression нужный вам кусок (это лямбда, в ней body типа MemberExpression, в нем Member). И подставляете его вместо `typeof(T).GetProperty("DayOfWeek")`

Answer (score 2):

Всё получилось:

```
static Expression<Func<T, int>> BuildDayIndexInWeekSelector<T>(
    Expression<Func<T, DayOfWeek>> dayOfWeekSelector,
    DayOfWeek weekStartsWith)
{
    int daysInWeek = 7;
    var parameterExp = dayOfWeekSelector.Parameters[0];
    var daysShiftExp = Expression.Constant(daysInWeek - (int)weekStartsWith);
    var daysInWeekExp = Expression.Constant(daysInWeek);
    var dayOfWeekExp =
        Expression.Convert(
            dayOfWeekSelector.Body,
            typeof(int));
    var bodyExp =
        Expression.Modulo(
            Expression.Add(
                dayOfWeekExp,
                daysShiftExp),
            daysInWeekExp);
    var lambdaExp =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(
            bodyExp,
            parameterExp);
    return lambdaExp;
}
```

Используется так:

```
var schedules =
    db.Schedules
      .OrderBy(
          BuildDayIndexInWeekSelector<Schedule>(
              s => s.DayOfWeek,
              weekStartsWith: DayOfWeek.Monday))
      .ToList();
```