# Для чего нужны деревья выражений?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, лямбда-выражение, деревья-выражений

Собственно вопрос, для чего они нужны и когда может потребоваться генерить их ручками в коде?

Звучит как что-то мощное, но что-то не могу придумать, когда это может понадобится.

Comment: Когда хочется, чтобы запрос выполнился на сервере, а не на клиенте. В основном, динамические запросы с фильтрами по различным полям. Вы понимаете разницу между IQueryable и IEnumerable?

Comment: Речь идет об SQL-запросах?

Comment: @iluxa1810, не только.

Comment: *но что-то не могу придумать, когда это может понадобится* — ну вот же вчера было: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/823830/218063

Comment: Для использования их как унифицированный dsl, который можно транслировать на разные области.