# EntityFramework Core. Трансляция Expression в SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть, например, вот такой запрос

```
context.SomeEntity.Where(e => e.SomeProperty.NestedProperty == 1);
```

Так вот, мне нужно преобразовать `e.SomeProperty.NestedProperty` по собственным правилам. Как я могу это провернуть?

Comment: Для сложных преобразований можно использовать хранимки или посмотреть в сторону интеграции clr библиотеки

Comment: что значит преобразовать? Как именно преобразовать? Для какой цели? Можно самому построить expression который затем передать в where, можно свой provider написать, все зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/823830/218063

Comment: @Grundy, это значит, что e.SomeProperty.NestedProperty при условии некоторых атрибутов на свойствах должно превратиться в "e->'SomeProperty'->'NestedProperty'. Ну примерно. Провайдер мне писать не нужно. А вот как воткнуть свой экспрешшн туда?

Comment: `"e->'SomeProperty'->'NestedProperty'` — что значит эта запись?

Comment: @АндрейNOP это кусочек SQL запроса. Нечто вместо "alias.Property"

Comment: Что за БД? Первый раз вижу такой синтаксис

Comment: @АндрейNOP это запрос к полям json и jsonb в postgresql

Comment: Ну тогда: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43089058/6766879 "Всё уже украдено до нас" Еще: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/EF-JSON-Support.html

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ничего там не украдено. По ссылке нет ответа на мой вопрос. А по поводу продуктов деварта, у меня нет на них денег. И к тому же в их решении есть только функции. Функции я и сам уже сделал, а мне нужны именно свойства.

Comment: Ага, я понял, это извлечение части json на стороне сервера. Сомневаюсь что одними `Expressions` это решается. Откуда провайдеру знать что выражение надо превращать во что-то другое? Так что либо свой провайдер, либо писать SQL ручками (возможно часть sql, там же есть перегрузка where, принимающая строку?), либо парсить json на клиентской стороне

Comment: @АндрейNOP, думаю, это можно решить экспрешшном. Откуда провайдеру знать, что выражение надо превращать во что-то другое, решится атрибутами на свойствах. Вопрос сейчас в том, как в механизм построения дерева и механизм построения запроса из дерева вклиниться. Не уверен, куда именно мне надо вклиниться, поэтому надо сразу 2 инжекта. Все что я знаю - это возможно без написания собственного провайдера. Но я не знаю как.

Comment: Наверное вы правы, надо посмотреть исходники той же `EF.Functions.Like`, хотя, в принципе ef core весь код доступен

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну да, надо. Этим и занимаюсь. Просто думал вдруг кто уже делал подобное и подскажет. :)

Comment: @iRumba, посмотрите, пожалуйста, не исказил ли я ваш вопрос своей правкой. А какого типа у вас свойство `SomeProperty` в C#-модели?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, исказили. SomeEntity имеет поле типа json (об этом не было речи в вопросе). Этот json разворачивается в некую структуру. В данном случае `{"SomeProperty": {"NestedProperty": 1}}`. То есть SomeProperty это класс, у которого есть свойство NestedProperty. А вообще я не хотел конкретики в вопросе... она сбивает с толку. Суть именно в том, чтобы вклиниться в построение дерева. А json там или нет - это уже конкретная реализация.

Comment: _Откуда провайдеру знать, что выражение надо превращать во что-то другое, решится атрибутами на свойствах._ - провайдер понимает только свои атрибуты. На какие-то левые он не обращает внимания.

Comment: В обычном EF есть такая фича - Interception. В EF Core, вроде, до сих пор её нет. Но можно попробовать перегрузить [SaveChanges](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/29/implementing-seeding-custom-conventions-and-interceptors-in-ef-core-1-0/) или использовать [DiagnosticSource](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/interception-in-entity-framework-core).