# Сортировка не материализованных данных через LINQ с определенной логикой

Tags: c#, linq

Есть статусы в `enum` - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. В БД есть записи, которые имеют эти статусы. Нужно выбрать все эти записи, но отсортировать определенным образом - сначала должны идти записи со статусом 2, далее со статусом 4, далее со статусом 3 и потом все остальные.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что такое "статус"? Обычно подобные перечисления делают как `enum` со всем необходимым. Если у вас просто `int`, то мне кажется это плохое решение... Ну а если у вас `enum`, то просто разместите в нем объекты в том порядке, в котором надо сортировать и делайте простой `.OrderBy(x=>x.Status)`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ. да. Статус является `enum`. Проблема в том, что функционал завязан уже на имеющиеся значения.

Comment: Я вам не говорю менять значения, я говорю разместите их в том порядке, в котором хотите видеть сортировку (`enum Status { 2, 4, 3  ... }`), ну или задайте им сами, через `=` нужное `int` значение.

Comment: Если вы хотите сортировать на стороне бд, придется составлять выражение для этого, которое потом транслируется в запрос, смотрите эти топики: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/821745/218063 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/823830/218063

Comment: Также, можно завести в бд ещё одну таблицу — карту, которая будет содержать колонки: id статуса и order_id для сортировки. Делаете join к ней и сортируете по order_id

Comment: @АндрейNOP Спасибо. Буду исследовать

Comment: @Popee если вам нужно извлекать из БД, а только потом сортировать, то очень просто для ваших записей сделать IEqualityComparer, и в нём прописать логику что за чем должно идти. Но это работает только локально, уже после извлечения из БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было найден:

```
    .OrderBy(x => (int)x.Status == 5 ? 1
                  (int)x.Status == 4 ? 2
                  (int)x.Status == 1 ? 3
                  (int)x.Status == 2 ? 4
                  (int)x.Status == 3 ? 5 : 6);
```

Или:

```
    .OrderBy(x => x.Status == MyEnum.StatusFive ? 1
                  x.Status == MyEnum.StatusFour ? 2
                  x.Status == MyEnum.StatusOne ? 3
                  x.Status == MyEnum.StatusTwo ? 4
                  x.Status == MyEnum.StatusThree ? 5 : 6);
```